# Projecting additional fields with $group aggregator in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following query:

```
HOST_USAGE.aggregate([{
    '$match': {'sysstat.host.nodename': host}
    }, {
        '$project': {'ts': '$sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp'}
    }, {
        '$unwind': '$ts'
    }, {
        '$unwind': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu'
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': 0,
            'all-usr': {'$max': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu.usr'}
        }
    }])
```

However, there's an additional field that I would like to grab, `$sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp[*].time`

[image]

I've tried just,

```
'$group': {
    '_id': 0,
    'all-usr': {'$max': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu.usr'},
    'time': '$ts.time'
}
```

but this gives an error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: exception: the group aggregate field 'time' must be defined as an expression inside an object`. How can I `$group` some fields, and also project other fields into the returned dataset?

Answer (score 1):

If you're grouping any field you must group all fields. You could use $push or $addToSet to get an array of timestamps:

```
HOST_USEAGE.aggregate([{
    '$match': {'sysstat.host.nodename': 1}
}, {
    # Rename the field for brevity.
    '$project': {'ts': '$sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp'}
}, {
    '$unwind': '$ts'
}, {
    '$unwind': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu'
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': 0,
        'all-usr': {'$sum': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu.usr'},
        'times': {'$addToSet': '$ts.time'}
    }
}])))
```

I recommend `$addToSet` to avoid duplicate times in the output array: `$push` would you give one copy of each time per "cpu-load-all" entry because of how $unwind works.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to do is actually grab the distinct time at which `$max` was found. Is that possible here, or do I need to restructure my query entirely?